# Loading files with the most recent date in R

Tags: r

Say I have a file that I would like to load in R - let's call it `file.csv`. It's fairly easy to load this into R.

Unfortunately in my case multiple versions of this file exist and each file has a date appended to it... so that what I really have in my directory is a list of files such as:

`file - 02-19-2013.csv`
`file - 02-18-2013.csv`
`file - 02-17-2013.csv`

... and so on

I am wondering how I can go about loading the file with the most recent date in R?

Comment: With a more sorting friendly date format you wouldn't need to parse the file names, since `list.files` returns the file names in alphabetical order.

Comment: Do you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762224/how-to-sort-files-list-by-date/13762544

Comment: That only works if the date in the file name is the same as the creation date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the date out of the file name string (try `substr`).

And then convert it to a date object using any of the numerous date parsing functions.

And then order by the order of those date objects.

Or if you are lucky you might just discover that your date format in your file names sort in the right way just by using `sort` on your vector of filenames...

Comment: This is correct. Your only choice is to list all the files matching that pattern and then extract and parse the date component of each file.

Comment: Thanks for this! The right date-parsing function in R appears to be `as.POSIXct`